# Render a UserControl to an Image with a different size then the one at which it is displayed?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, render

I have a UserControl that is part of my application, I am rendering it to an Image, but it is being rendered with the dimensions at which it is currently being displayed. What I would want is to render it to fixed dimensions say 500x500, but without having it render with the new dimensions to the user.

```
UserControl temp = pane.Content;
RadBitmap radImage = new RadBitmap(temp); // Renders UserControl to Image
PngFormatProvider provider = new PngFormatProvider();

return provider.Export(radImage); // returns the Image as a png encoded Byte Array
```

Note: My UserControl is the child of another Control which dictate the size of my UserControl.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. What you need to do is resize the VisualParent of your UserControl at the dimensions you want your picture to be, render your UserControl to an image, and revert the size of the VisualParent back to what it was.

```
        UserControl userControl = pane.Content;
        ContentPresenter visualParent = (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(userControl) as ContentPresenter);

        double oldWidth = visualParent.Width;
        double oldHeight = visualParent.Height;

        visualParent.Width = BitmapImageWidth;
        visualParent.Height = BitmapImageHeight;
        visualParent.UpdateLayout(); // This is required! To apply the change in Width and Height

        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(BitmapImageWidth, BitmapImageHeight);
        bmp.Render(userControl, null);
        bmp.Invalidate(); // Only once you Invalidate is the Control actually rendered to the bmp
        RadBitmap radImage = new RadBitmap(bmp);

        visualParent.Width = oldWidth; // Revert back to original size
        visualParent.Height = oldHeight; // Revert back to original size

        return new PngFormatProvider().Export(radImage); // returns the Image as a png encoded Byte Array
```